# R counting words in a string and storing in an array

Tags: r, stringr

I have wrote a function to identify the number of words in a sentence and it is scalable as I may want to track the counts of more than one word as I write my code. Problem though is outputting the function into an array. I can generate the counts and produce an int array. However it only outputs the final entry as opposed to producing a matrix

```r
Words = c("Hero","Dragon","Sword","Level up")
game_description = c("The hero slayed the dragon with his mighty sword",
                    "The protagonist received a level up following a fight", 
                    "The dragon lost his temper and started to level up")

WCounts = sapply(Words, function(x) str_count(if(is.atomic(game_description))
             {game_description} else {" "},regex(x,ignore_case=TRUE)))
```

output

```r
WCounts

  [1,]     0
  [2,]     1
  [3,]     0
  [4,]     1
```

Trying to out as either 2,

```r
          [1,] [2,] [3,]
  [1,]     1    0    0
  [2,]     1    0    1
  [3,]     1    0    0
  [4,]     0    1    1


          ["Hero"] ["Dragon"] ["Sword"] ["Level up"]
  [1,]        1        1          1          0
  [2,]        0        0          0          1
  [3,]        0        1          0          1
```

Comment: I cam not getting the samee 'WCounts' output you showed.  It is giving exactly as the last expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the same code and get the expected output

```
WCounts = sapply(Words, function(x) str_count(if(is.atomic(game_description))
             {game_description} else {" "},regex(x,ignore_case=TRUE)))

WCounts
#      Hero Dragon Sword Level up
#[1,]    1      1     1        0 
#[2,]    0      0     0        1
#[3,]    0      1     0        1
```

---

Or a bit more compact

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(str_extract_all(game_description, paste0("(?i)", 
         paste(Words, collapse="|"))))
```

---

Or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map(Words, ~ str_count(game_description, regex(.x, ignore_case = TRUE))) %>%
          do.call(cbind, .)
```

---

Or we can use `base R` methods with `table` and `regmatches/regexpr`

```
+(table(stack(setNames(lapply(Words, function(x) 
  regmatches(game_description, regexpr(x, game_description, 
      ignore.case = TRUE))), seq_along(Words)))[2:1]) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `sapply` over `game_description` and `Words` with `grepl`

```
out <- +(sapply(game_description, function(x) 
                sapply(Words, grepl, x, ignore.case = TRUE)))
colnames(out) <- NULL
out

#         [,1] [,2] [,3]
#Hero        1    0    0
#Dragon      1    0    1
#Sword       1    0    0
#Level up    0    1    1
```